# how to extend django views/templates in a forward looking way

Tags: python, django, templates, view

i'm looking for a way to extend a django template/view.

my first implementation consists of two models (`clients/models.py`):

```
class Client(models.Model):
    ...

class Address(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    ...
```

and its fairly simple template (`clients/detail.html`) :

```
{{client.name}}
Address: {{client.address.street}}, {{client.address.zipcode}} {{client.address.city}}
```

as my application grows, a new app was born: 'invoices'.

it is again very simple (`invoices/models.py`):

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(clients.models.Client)
    ...
```

now my clients details-view needs to display invoices, so i create and override `clients/detail.html` in my 'invoices' app.

good for now.

later on i created a third app 'quotes'.
again my clients details-view needs to display quotes.

if i create `clients/detail.html` in my 'clients' i will loose the ability to display invoices.

because the 'invoices' and 'quotes' app are indipendent.

my first idea was to create something like a SubView-class
which 'invoices' and 'quotes' can extend and then register their implementation somewhere.

a template should look like this:

```
{{client.name}}
Address: {{client.address.street}}, {{client.address.zipcode}} {{client.address.city}}

{% for view in views %}
    <h1>{{view.title}}</h1>
    {{view.get_html}}
{% endfor %}
```

is this a good way to go and should i use a `admin.site`-like implementation for registering my sub-views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Django one `url` in `urls.py` should ideally use *one* `view`, just to keep things simple.

I would therefore adopt the approach of putting all the required context in your *one* view for this screen (I think you already have this via foreign keys in your model). Then, rather than doing what you call "SubView-class" I would go for the Django template [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include).

Example:

```
{% for invoice in client.invoices %}
    {% include "invoice-detail.html" with invoice=invoice %}
{% endfor %}
```

This renders each invoice's detail for all the invoices of the `client`. Notice how this is in line with the [DRY principle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry).

Comment: hey josvic, ideally i want to keep the `clients/detail.html` free from knowledge about 'invoices' or 'quotes'. thank you anyway.it is a good practice (+1)

Comment: @mo. Exactly, all `invoices` or `quotes` specific knowledge would go into the templates you `include` in the main `client` template.

Comment: but if add another app, i dont want to change `clients/detail.html` again.it could be an option if i override this template project-wide.because then it knows every app...

Comment: @mo. Not sure If I understand why you having these models in different apps should matter at template level. Nevertheless changing individual models should trigger changes only in the specific template for that model.

Comment: its just a fictive project :)

Comment: @Josvic Zammit `with invoice=invoice` in your `include` tag is redundant. You are free to use base context in included template

Comment: @San4ez Yes it is, just "exhibiting" the possible usage(s) of [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include) tag.